# Facepy unable to upload image to Facebook

Tags: python, facebook-graph-api, post, photos, facepy

I'm trying to use [Facepy](https://github.com/jgorset/facepy), a sort of API for Facebook and Python, to simply post an image from my desktop to a Facebook page for which I have the authorization code and publish_stream and upload_photo permissions.  (**UPDATE**:  how do I **verify** that that is true?)

It's not working for me, though it *is* working for the author of Facepy.  I'm at a loss for what is causing the issue.  When I run this code, taken from the Facepy site (and using a .jpg on my computer):

**UPDATE**:  This is the entirety of the code I am running:

```
from facepy import GraphAPI

print 'Trying Facebook page...'
my_token = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
graph = GraphAPI(my_token)

# Get my latest posts
my_posts = graph.get("me/posts")

 #Post a photo of a parrot
graph.post(path = "me/photos",source = open("python.png"))

print 'Done.'
```

Facepy returns this error:

```
Error: (#1) An unknown error occurred
```

I have tried it, unsuccessfully, with Python 2.5 and Python 2.7 on WinXP.  Facepy can, however, get my latest posts, with `graph.get('me/posts')`

Any advice to get this to work would be appreciated.

Comment: actually, I am even facing this error. So, I tried something line this `graph.post(path="me/feed", picture=open("parrot.jpeg).read()` Its not showing any error but posting an invalid image. `me/feed`

Comment: @Surya OK, no answers yet.  Not sure if you edited it this way but if you did, please don't edit the title to include Django; that is, for my question, irrelevant.  Thanks.

Comment: hey, I literally played all possibilities on this `graph.post()` and found one working method. If your image is a HttpResponse i.e, a web URL.. use `graph.post(path="me/posts", source=urllib2.urlopen(imag url) )` this is working

Comment: @Surya Ah, interesting, but for me it doesn't help.  I want to go from an image *on my desktop* to Facebook.  If it is already an image online that means I've already posted it to another site only to have to read it back in with urllib2, which is absurd.  I cannot understand why this works for the author of Facepy but not us.

Comment: Which access token have you been using, you want to post as a user to the page or as the page itself?

Comment: @phwd I'm not sure which access token it is, but I got it via this URL: 'https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx&scope=publish_stream&redirect_uri=https://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html&response_type=token'  I then logged in, agreed that it was OK to post to the wall, and got the access token.  I don't understand your distinction between posting as the user or as the page itself.  Ultimately I want users of desktop software to post photos to their Facebook page, if that helps to understand my need.

Comment: A Facebook page is a fan page, do you mean you want users to post to their *personal* *profile/timeline* or a *fan* *page* they own?

Comment: Probably both, though the first order of business would be the personal profile such that a person can share photos with one's friends (which is I believe is what I was trying to do).  Later it would be great to be able to post to a fan page, too.

Comment: Try resetting your token / using a next one. The call works I've used it many times.

Comment: @phwd My old token had run out.  I got a new one.  I just tried it again.  Same exact problem.  Is it possible I am doing something wrong?

Comment: Could you post all your code from start (the import of facey till adding the token (use xxxxx) to the call) to finish? Maybe it might be a bug with your set that will have to escalate to the author or Facebook. But currently I cannot repro because it works for me

Comment: @phwd OK, now posted everything I'm using.

Comment: I have tested against your full code and I see no errors. The photo updates to a user profile as it should.

You are most likely encountering a bug with this specific application. Try doing the call via the Graph API Explorer or cURL and see if you receive the same error. If you do, submit a bug. If you don't uninstall and reinstall your facepy.

Note: I am using Python 2.7.2

Comment: @phwd Thanks for trying.  Unfortunately, I tried the Graph API Explorer back in April; it only allows you to upload from a URL, which isn't testing my problem (uploading from a file on one's computer), though that did work.  I don't have cURL, but I have seen others can use it to upload a photo from the computer.  I am trying either Python 2.5 or 2.7.2, and neither work.  I can't imagine the small Facepy script needs to be reinstalled, but I might as well try it.  Frustrating.  Thanks again for all your efforts.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. And apparently found the answer.

According to [GitHub page](https://github.com/jgorset/facepy), a `source` parameter needs a `rb` mode:

```
graph.post(
path = 'me/photos',
source = open('parrot.jpg', 'rb')
```

Works for me (with Python 3 & Graph API 2.8).

To publish from URL, you can use `url`:

```
par = {
    "caption": "Some text",
    "url": "https://example.com/1.jpg"}

send_post = graph.post(path='me/photos', **par)
```